# Excluding a git remote from "fetch --all"

Tags: git, git-remote

Is it possible to have configured remotes in git that are only fetched when formally requested by its name? So they would be excluded of operations like `fetch --all`.

Imagine a dormant (disabled, or something) remote called "my-no-auto-fetch-remote":

```
$ git fetch my-no-auto-fetch-remote
```

(it's fetched)

```
$ git fetch --all
```

(the my-no-auto-fetch-remote shouldn't be fetched)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a configuration `skipFetchAll` for remotes.

From the documentation on: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/1.9.2

> remote..skipFetchAll
>
> If true, this remote will be skipped by
>   default when updating using git-fetch[1] or the update subcommand of
>   git-remote[1].

As there is no option at command line when adding or changing a remote, I had to put that configuration editing the `.git/config` file, as:

```
[remote "my-remote"]
        url = git@the-repository-url
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/my-remote/*
        skipFetchAll = true
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no: `--all` means *all*.  But you *can* define remote *groups*, and use `git remote update` to update the groups.  Put the normally-unavailable remote into a group that's not the default group.  See [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) for details.

(`git fetch` also works with groups, I just prefer to use `git remote` when dealing with groups and `git fetch` for one individual remote, myself.  Probably a holdover from a decade-plus ago...)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with a bash trick:

```
git remote | grep -v the-repo-i-dont-want | xargs git fetch
```

Might turn it into a script or git alias.