# Configure git to always fetch only current branch and master

Tags: git, monorepo, git-fetch, git-refspec

Is it possible to configure git to, *by default*, when using `git fetch`, fetch *only* the current branch and master from the remote, without explicitly mentioning the current branch name?

I know that I can achieve this exact fetch with this command:

```
git fetch origin $(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD) master:master
```

But I would like to have the same behavior when I run only

```
git fetch
```

Is that possible to configure? For instance, by some magic refspec in the `.git/config` file.

Note that, in the configuration, I don't want to hard code the name of the current branch, and I don't want to use aliases.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not interested in [aliases](https://github.com/meagar/dotfiles/blob/master/.bash_profile#L11)? I consider them a normal and more or less essential part of using Git. There are many limitations on the configuration of *most* pieces of CLI software. You overcome these limitations with aliases.

Comment: The reason I avoid aliases is that I want my git-related muscle memory to be usable in a generic environment. My muscle memory is to type `git fetch` and that works reasonably well everywhere. An alias will not work everywhere.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54934221/3717691

Comment: You want to set `remote.origin.fetch` to the list of references to fetch when no ref specs are given to `git fetch`. Run something like `git config --local remote.origin.fetch refs/heads/master:refs/HEAD`?

Comment: (See `git help fetch` for more details.)

Comment: @jeppe as far as I can tell `skipFetchAll = true` only changes the behaviour of `git fetch --all`, by skipping that remote entirely, which is not what I want.

Comment: @chepner configuring to fetch master is not hard, but I've found it hard to configure git to fetch the current branch without naming it explicitly in the config. I don't want to have to hack the `config` file every time I create a new feature branch. But I live in a monorepo, so I also don't want to fetch all branches by default. (I have read `git help fetch`)

Comment: @KlasMellbourn This is why I keep my dotfiles in a publicly accessible place, so I can fetch the alises I'm used to using pretty much anywhere. Aliases give you a lot of huge efficiency gains that you'll use dozens or hundreds of times a day. This easily outweighs the cost of having to set them up on each new environment.

Comment: There is no way to do this directly, *but* you can easily (well...) write you own `git` front end alias-or-command that inspects the operation to be done. If it's `git fetch`, check to see if there are options; if not, don't run `git fetch`, run `git fetch <current-remote> <current-branch-name>` instead.